# Create a HttpContext manually?

Tags: c#, httpcontext

I have an authentication to a target System (SharePoint) which needs a httpContext to store tokens etc, which works fine on a web application.

Now I need to use the same authentication on the same machine using a console application which has no HttpContext obviously.

Is it possible to create a "dummy" httpContext to use here?
(I am NOT talking about mocking for unit tests, but to use in the main code)

Comment: So you pass HttpContext to third party api and then what happens? How this api uses context?

Comment: It reads data from the HttpRequest (AccesToken, etc) and als writes Data into the response.

Comment: So you basically want to provide access token and then intercept that response in console application? Reading the response is the end goal?